# How to create a data frame aggregating the daily ticket numbers to monthly count?

Tags: r

I am having the list of ticket numbers for each date. Date column is transformed to data but the ticket number column is a text.

```
Created       Ticket
01-Jan-19   a1
02-Jan-19   a2
03-Jan-19   a3
04-Jan-19   a4
05-Jan-19   a5
06-Jan-19   a6
07-Jan-19   a7
08-Jan-19   a8
09-Jan-19   a9
10-Jan-19   a10
11-Jan-19   a11
12-Jan-19   a12
13-Jan-19   a13
14-Jan-19   a14
15-Jan-19   a15
16-Jan-19   a16
17-Jan-19   a17
18-Jan-19   a18
19-Jan-19   a19
01-Feb-19   a20
02-Feb-19   a21
03-Feb-19   a22
04-Feb-19   a23
```

Tried to use floor data in R but since the ticket number column is character I am not able to use it.

```
data <- read.csv(file = 'D:\\DS Data\\SampleTickets.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header = TRUE)

str(data)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(Created = dmy(Created))

data %>% group_by(month=floor_date(Created, "month")) %>%
  summarize(amount=sum(Ticket))
```

I am expecting a data frame output like..

```
CreatedMonth     CountOfTickets
1/1/2019             18
1/2/2019              4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there: Just use `n()` instead of `sum(Ticket)` to count the number of rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
  mutate(Created = dmy(Created)) %>%
  group_by(month = floor_date(Created, "month")) %>%
  summarize(amount = n())
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>   month      amount
>   <date>      <int>
> 1 2019-01-01     19
> 2 2019-02-01      4
> ```

However, there is a shortcut which uses `count()`:

```
data %>% 
  count(CreatedMonth = dmy(Created) %>% floor_date("month"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>   CreatedMonth     n
>   <date>       <int>
> 1 2019-01-01      19
> 2 2019-02-01       4
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` version:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .N, by = .(CreatedMonth = floor_date(dmy(Created), "month"))]
```

> ```
>    CreatedMonth  N
> 1:   2019-01-01 19
> 2:   2019-02-01  4
> ```

#### Data

```
data <- readr::read_table("Created       Ticket
01-Jan-19   a1
02-Jan-19   a2
03-Jan-19   a3
04-Jan-19   a4
05-Jan-19   a5
06-Jan-19   a6
07-Jan-19   a7
08-Jan-19   a8
09-Jan-19   a9
10-Jan-19   a10
11-Jan-19   a11
12-Jan-19   a12
13-Jan-19   a13
14-Jan-19   a14
15-Jan-19   a15
16-Jan-19   a16
17-Jan-19   a17
18-Jan-19   a18
19-Jan-19   a19
01-Feb-19   a20
02-Feb-19   a21
03-Feb-19   a22
04-Feb-19   a23")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` we can first convert `Created` column to actual Date and group them by each month and count number of tickets for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Created = as.Date(Created, "%d-%b-%y")) %>%
  arrange(Created) %>%
  mutate(Yearmon = format(Created, "%B-%Y"), 
         Yearmon = factor(Yearmon, levels = unique(Yearmon))) %>%
  group_by(Yearmon) %>%
  summarise(count = n())


# Yearmon       count
#  <fct>         <int>
#1 January-2019     19
#2 February-2019     4
```